# External keyboard function keys suddenly stopped working

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I use a Logitech K850 Bluetooth keyboard with my MBP on MacOS 12.3.1.  I had configured my fn keys to be the standard F1, F2, F3 instead of the special feature keys like changing the volume:

[image]

Suddenly though, this has stopped working.  If I press F8, it now mutes the speakers instead of actually being the F8 key.  I have tried:

- restarting
- unpair/pair the keyboard again
- untick and tick the option in the screenshot above

All don't make a difference.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

FIXED.

There's a "fn lock key" on my keyboard that I accidentally enabled.  It's on the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and has a picture of a padlock with <kbd>fn</kbd> inside.  To toggle this "fn lock" feature, press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: yaaas thank you - My Logitech ERGO K860 keyboard has a lock button to the right of F12. I inadvertently pressed it and my media keys stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful Function key on a Macbook is F3 ...to jump between multiple screens or windows. However, when you plug in an external keyboard the F3 key does not work as it did on the Macbook (Dell keyboard , F3 is audio increase)
F3 on Macbook is actually "Mission Control" and same functionality can be achieved by hitting "control" (or ^) plus the "up-arrow" key. This may differ from Osx versions but can be confirmed by going to "System" > "Keyboard Shortcuts" > "Mission Control" to see what shortcut is assigned to "Mission Control"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).